# Passing arguments to an r file using commandArgs is not working in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The following correctly prints "hello world":

main_script.R

```
commandArgs <- function() "hello world"
source('file_to_source.R')
```

file_to_source.R

```
word<-(commandArgs())
print(word)
```

However, if the code from main_script.R is run from within a Shiny app, file_to_source.R will print:

[1] "RStudio"       "--interactive"

Is there a way around this? I'd really like to be able to pass variables to another script from within shiny.

Comment: Why do you need to use `source`? Why not just make function?

Comment: If you want to pass variables between scripts, you shouldn't be overwriting the `commandArgs` function. There should probably be functions in your sourced files that you can call with whatever parameters you like. They shouldn't auto-execute with command line parameters if you want them to be reusable.

Comment: Upon review, I should probably rewrite it as a function. Thanks to you both.